# Javascript map CSV string to JSON array

Tags: javascript, json, api, csv, middleware

this one baffles me and I'm not even sure I'm searching the correct keywords for possible explanations.

I am sending an RPC to a remote server.  The response I get is just a comma-delimited string with values (no keys) like so:

```
val1,val2,val3,val4,val5,val6,val7,val8,val9
```

When I receive this response I need to map these values through JS to keys (hard-coded, I designate) and generate a JSON array like this:

```
{
  "response": {
    "mykey1" : "val1",
    "mykey2" : "val2",
    "mykey3" : "val3",
    "mykey4" : "val4",
    "mykey5" : "val5",
    "mykey6" : "val6",
    "mykey7" : "val7",
    "mykey8" : "val8",
    "mykey9" : "val9"
  }
}
```

Can anybody nudge me in the right direction...sample code or tutorials that are close to what I am looking for?  This is a for middleware script that gets called when server receives the response.

This is my first post here, been looking a long time learning and applying in Obj-C and as I am learning Swift, but JS is new to me.  I apologize in advance if I am breaking any protocols by asking for help without posting my feeble attempts at figuring this out...

Comment: Do you know what your keys are? What if you have 15 keys and only get back 5 `val`s?

Comment: Hello mariocatch.  Yes I do, I just updated my post.  the string I receive will always have the same number of values (in my case it is 11) and will always be in the same order.  If value is not returned, it will look like this val1,val2,,val4,,,val7...but there will always be x number of comma delimeters.

Comment: Just use `String.split(',')` then you can do whatever you want with the resulting Array. The Object you want to create with the results should make sense. If you just want to use those keys, why even bother making an Object at all?

Comment: Hi PHPGlue, I need to return a json object to the client with keys and values.  Using `String.split(',')` can I / should I assign each value to a var?  If it helps, I am using Tyk API gateway and it requires a json response object.  I need to create a middleware script to receive the response and convert it to json...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can `split` the response on comma, which will give you an array.
2. Since both arrays (keys and vals) are the same length, you can loop over either and create your array of objects that way. See below

```js
var response = 'val1,val2,val3,val4,val5';
var keys = [
  'key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4', 'key5'
];

var dict = [];
var vals = response.split(',');

vals.forEach(function(val, i) {
  dict[keys[i]] = val;
});

console.log(dict);
```

Comment: Okay great matiocatch!  Let me work this a bit and get back with results.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Read my comment, then check this out:

```
var result = 'val1,val2,val3,val4,val5,val6,val7,val8,val9';
// real question should be why result is not JSON already
var resArray = result.split(',');
console.log(resArray[0]); // first result
console.log(resArray[1]); // second result
```

Comment: Thank you PHPGlue, I'll give this a shot.  I can't change the endpoint response, it is a payment processing system already gone through card brand certifications, etc.  Any changes to it require all sorts of drama.  Thank you!